# Should i rather use a subquery or a combined WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

This specific situation may seem a bit silly, but i just want to know how i should solve it: there is a table (schools) and in this table you find all students with their school-id. The order is completely random, but with a SELECT statement you can sort it.

```
CREATE TABLE schools (school_id int, name varchar(32), age ...);
```

Now i want to search for a student by his name (with LIKE '%name%'), but only if he's in a certain school.
I already tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM `schools` WHERE `school_id` = 33 and `name` LIKE '%max%';
```

But then i realized, that i could also use subqueries like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `schools` WHERE `school_id` = 33) AS a
      WHERE a.name LIKE '%max%';
```

Which way is more efficient/has a higher performance?

Comment: I'd say the latter adds an unnecessary level of indirection that _could*_ hurt performance, and you'd be at the optimizer's mercy. I'd only rewrite it the second way if it proved to have significant performance benefits from forcing evaluation, but even in that case only after looking into things like index hints. _* example, if you swap the conditions in the latter, you could end up forcing MySQL to ignore an index on school_id._

Comment: You could test this faster than ask us

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/) keyword to see exactly how each query is executed.

I'd say it's almost a definite that these two will execute identically.

Answer (score 1):

The query optimizer will probably choose the same plan for both queries. If you want to know for sure, look at the execution plan when you execute each query.

Answer (score 1):

The query without the subquery is probably more efficient in MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM `schools`
WHERE `school_id` = 33 and `name` LIKE '%max%';
```

MySQL has this nasty tendency to materialize subqueries -- that is, to actually run the subquery and save it as a temporary table (it is getting better, though).  Most other databases do not do this.  So, in other databases, the two should be equivalent.

MySQL is smart enough to use an index, if available, for `school_id`, even though there are other comparisons.  If no indexes are available, it will be doing a full table scan, which will probably dominate the performance.